# Having trouble installing R package - "scales.so" not found, S3 methods declared in NAMESPACE but not found

Tags: r, cran

I'm trying to install a package in CRAN and one of the dependencies is throwing this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘viridis’ ...
** package ‘viridis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: S3 methods ‘fullseq.Date’, ‘fullseq.POSIXt’, ‘fullseq.numeric’, ‘print.trans’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘scales.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘viridis’
```

This is on Linux 12.04.5 LTS,

R version 3.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can solve this with

```
install.packages('scales')
```